# New Tags for Pi3b+

Tags: bug, tags

Earlier this week, I created the pi-3b+ tag, which is currently used by 3 questions (including one I just added). However, while doing that I notice someone added a rpi3b+ tag (used by one question). Tag links can be found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags).

Is there a consensus on which is or should be the canonical tag name? Note I named mine based on the existing tag names pi-2 pi-3 and pi-b+. One could argue that I should have done pi-3-b+, based on the original pi b+ tag (pi-b+), but that looked too busy.

If there is a consensus, can we retag the questions using the deprecated tag and delete the tag?

Comment: Anyone care to update the tag info for the pi-models tag? I will use my "currently on mobile" excuse to not do it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I seem to recall we went through this a while back to standardize things such that all the model tags start with `pi-` then the model, sans `b` for the `2` and `3` (although I notice [pi-2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-2) [has *four* synonyms already](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/pi-2/synonyms), neither of these has the `b` suffix as a synonym, so I've suggested that).

So I've merged [pi3b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi3b%2b) -> [pi-3b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-3b%2b).  If anyone is so inclined, please go and approve my suggested synonyms for [pi-2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-2) and [pi-3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-3) so we don't have to go through that later.

Comment: You can approve your own synonyms, from [this page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) if you like, since you're a moderator (Although apparently it won't let you do that from the 'suggest a synonym' page even with a diamond. Odd.) Or you can leave it for the community to vote on, if that's your idea ;)

Comment: @aurora0001 all community votes on tags should preferably go through meta not via usage patterns alone. As you know ill-chosen tags get still promoted by the system since they are suggested to new users.